# Prevent modal from exit if clicked outside modal area

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I have a Jquery modal and I want to prevent it from closing if the area outside the modal is clicked, I searched on Google how to do it without success. How can I do this? here is the code that I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <title>Popup Login and Register</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font- awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<body>
 <div class="container">
    <a id="modal_trigger" href="#modal" class="btn">Click here to Login or register</a>

   <div id="modal" class="popupContainer" style="display:none;">
    <header class="popupHeader">
        <span class="header_title">Login</span>
        <span class="modal_close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span>
    </header>

    <section class="popupBody">
        <!-- Social Login -->
        <div class="social_login">

            <div class="action_btns">
                <div class="one_half"><a href="#" id="login_form" class="btn">Login</a></div>
                <div class="one_half last"><a href="#" id="register_form" class="btn">Sign up</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>          

    </section>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modal_trigger").leanModal({top : 200, overlay : 0.6, closeButton: ".modal_close" });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to achieve this. I was using a lean modal library (http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/). When the modal opens, a div called lean_overlay is created, which is upon the html page, so it create that nice effect that allows you to see the html page at background.

Checking the library, I found an event that is triggered when that lean_overlay div is clicked:

```
$("#lean_overlay").click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)}
```

So I deleted that line, and now nothing happens when clicking the lean_overlay div, so in that way when you click outside the modal, its not closed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to unbind the click event for the area outside of your modal.
Here's the code for it.

```
$("#container").unbind('click');
```

And, as your modal is inside the div container so you have to make modal as clickable by binding click event only for your modal as:

```
$("#modal").bind('click');
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks, but its not working, where should I place this code? I put it inside $( document ).ready(function() {, but it didn't worked

Comment: Z-index property of modal should be higher than div container. Set z-index:999 for modal

Comment: Still dont works. One thing that I forgot to mention is that I want to keep the black effect on the screen, just as it looks now but without exiting when clicking outside

Comment: Is that sarcasm? if you want to help, just edit the answer clearly

Comment: Dear vito, i have posted the solution clearly which clear your issue almost. If not, please provide us with jsfiddle so that it will be clear to point out the issue exactly with your code.

Comment: Your solution don't works, that's why I keep asking.

Comment: Then make put your code in jsfiddle. I will take a look at it to resolve your issue